# Comparing ranks from differently sized sets across conditions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, group-differences, ranks

I performed a treatment-control experiment, with $r$ repeats per group. Each repeat $i$ consists of a set of $n_i$ observations. Each observation $j$ consist of a rank $x_{ij}$ and a class indicator $c_{ij}$, either class $a$ or $b$. I am interested to know whether the rank distribution of observations of class $a$ differs across the two conditions. The trouble is that the number of observations $n_i$ as well as the class distribution varies over the repeats. Is there any rank test described in the literature for this purpose? I am willing to convert the ranks to quantiles if needed.

Comment: This is not entirely clear. How is the ranks $x_{ij}$ within each repeat, that is, they vary from $1,2,\dotsc, n_i$ or otherwise? It will also increase the prob of getting some answer if you tell us more of the context! Also, is there some pairing?